# Redirect part of the URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all the requested url to `/artigo/`
(except for links with `?dash`)

for example:

```
example.com/como-aprender-php/ --> example.com/artigo/como-aprender-php
```

with htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^dash [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /artigo/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`example.com/como-aprender-php/` --> `example.com/artigo/como-aprender-php`
`example.com/como-aprender-php/?dash` --> *don't redirect*

Note: redirect only applied to non-existing folders/files